# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch in Matlab with true index

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, mismatch

I wrote this for loop to do something and I'm sure the size of this result array is equal to 30 but I don't know why this error is appear about the mismatch dimension !

```
for rno=1:30
    PersonNumber = outputtrainingdata(rno);
    RealOutput = finaloutputforeachrow(rno,PersonNumber);
    if round(RealOutput) == 1
        result(rno) = 'True';    % Error in this line 
        %result = 'True'
        TrueTrainingcounter = TrueTrainingcounter+1;
    else
        result(rno) = 'False';
        %result = 'False'
    end

 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assign the *string* `'True'` (length = 4) to `result(rno)` (length = 1). Similarly you are trying to assign the *string* `'False'` (length = 5) to `result(rno)` (length = 1). This is why you're getting a dimensions mismatch error.

If you want `result` to actually hold these strings, then you'll want to use a cell array.

```
result = cell(1, 30);
```

And then assign to it using `{}`

```
result{rno} = 'True';
```

A much better approach is to use the logical values `true` and `false` rather than the strings `'True'` and `'False'`. Because `length(true) == 1`, we no longer will get a dimension mismatch.

```
result(rno) = round(RealOutput) == 1;
```

Comment: But what it's the relation between the size of true/false (value) with the size of result(rno)(It's empty array at the first time )  ? I don't understand that !

Comment: @SamahAhmed `length(result(rno))` is always 1. You can check it yourself.

Comment: I used the logical values and it's OK now , Thank you.